# Statically linking a runtime loadable extension in sqlite

Tags: android, c, sqlite

I'm trying to link sqlite [regexp](https://www.sqlite.org/src/artifact/a68d25c659bd2d89) extention statically. But there is a catastrophic lack of examples... Official documantation just says:

> "To statically link your extension, simply add the -DSQLITE_CORE compile-time option. The SQLITE_CORE macro causes the SQLITE_EXTENSION_INIT1 and SQLITE_EXTENSION_INIT2 macros to become no-ops. Then modify your application to invoke the entry point directly, passing in a NULL pointer as the third "pApi" parameter. ... If you will be opening multiple database connections in your application, rather than invoking the extension entry points for each database connection separately, you might want to consider using the sqlite3_auto_extension() interface to register your extensions and to cause them to be automatically started as each database connection is opened."

Again, there is no exmaples where exactly sqlite3_auto_extension should be called. Why it is so necessary to add -DSQLITE_CORE option? There is said nothing about it in the [Using SQLite](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1pqesu2pQQ3a3hjLVJ0SEg3Rm8/view) book (pp. 209-210). The both site and book tell about "application". But I need only sqlite functional and regexp extension provided by sqlite3.c amalgamation file and regexp.c extension.

Comment: If you look on page 211, it shows the extension being called in an sql statement.